# Environment variable is not bound in this Context

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, jndi

I'm struggling with an annoying problem and I have not found a solution yet. I must to lookup a variable (myWSURL) defined in the context.xml of Tomcat 7.0.11.

```
<Context>
    <Environment name="myWSURL" value="https://host.service" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

The snippet code I've been using to lookup the variable is

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context rootContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/");
String wsURL = (String) rootContext.lookup("myWSURL");
```

But, I'm receiving a

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name myWSURL is not bound in this Context
```

Have I forgotten any configuration? Is my code wrong?

Any tip is welcome. Thanks.